# Java URL Connection throws IOException with 403, works perfectly in browser

Tags: java, file, http, https, download

so I am currently trying to download the html of a website, however I ran into this problem where one website constantly gives me 403 back. I've already had that error in previous projects, and were always able to fix it with adding a User-Agent, however this time, nothing I tried helped. I even copied every single part of my header in my browser, but I still get 403 in Java, while it works perfectly with wget, or other programming languages. Maybe someone here can help me?

URL im trying to download is: [here](https://www.mediamarkt.de/de/product/_gigabyte-geforce-rtx-3050-gaming-oc-8gv-n3050gaming-oc-8gd-nvidia-grafikkarte-2786310.html)

I'm using the following code (I've copied them 1:1 from my request in firefox):

```
    if (file.exists()) {
        Files.delete(file.toPath());
    }
    HttpURLConnection httpcon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpcon.setRequestMethod("GET");
    httpcon.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
    httpcon.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
    httpcon.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-GB,en;q=0.5");
    httpcon.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
    httpcon.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
    httpcon.setRequestProperty("Host", "www.mediamarkt.de");
    httpcon.setRequestProperty("Sec-Fetch-Dest", "document");
    httpcon.setRequestProperty("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "navigate");
    httpcon.setRequestProperty("Sec-Fetch-Site", "none");
    httpcon.setRequestProperty("Sec-Fetch-User", "?1");
    httpcon.setRequestProperty("TE", "trailers");
    httpcon.setRequestProperty("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
    httpcon.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0");
    InputStream is = httpcon.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    BufferedWriter bwr = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        bwr.write(line);
    }

    is.close();
    br.close();
    bwr.close();
```

Comment: What version of Java are you using? I suspect it could be a problem with the version of TLS but I don't know offhand how to debug that.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was using OpenJDK 15, I just tried it with JDK 8, seems to give me the same exception.

Comment: You might try JDK 17, but the next thing I would look at is what is the root certificate that signed the website's certificate, and is that certificate known to the JDK you're using. You can find the certs in the file `lib/security/cacerts` under the JDK and you can list them with the command `keytool -list -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit`

Comment: I actually get a 403 when I try to retrieve it with `wget`.